# Problem with paths after build an exe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

The problem I have is that after build the exe of an kivy app, when I try to get the main path of the main.py file which is c:..../desktop/statistic/dist/salida/salida.exe, the path python is printing in the function I use to check is c:..../desktop/statistic/dis.
The code I use to get the path of the main file is this:

```py
application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If I create an script in that folder and use this code it prints the correct path, dont understand why it changes after make the exe.
The spec file I'm using for the exe if needed:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooser
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import threading
import os
import sys
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
import pkg_resources

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\adm\\Desktop\\StatisticAnalisis - copia\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\adm\\Desktop\\statistic'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn','win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='salida',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('C:\\Users\\adm\\Desktop\\StatisticAnalisis - copia'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)], 
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='salida')
```

Comment: What is the mentioned function doing? How does the print happen?

Comment: Never use `__file__` in a built app. It will no longer be accurate. Use the pgk_resources API instead.

Comment: @PetruTanas actually it prints the path, before it copy a file from a folder to an other

Comment: @Keith I will try it, thanks, where can I find information about pgk_

Comment: It's part of setuptools. https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html . I assume you're trying find a data file colocated with it. When you compile it, it gets built into the binary file and no long exists separately in the file system.

Comment: When the `.exe` from a `Pyinstaller` build is executed, a temporary folder is created where the bundled files are extracted. Have a look at the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file). It suggests using `bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))` to get the folder.